# J2me db option, jmesql

Tags: database, java-me, rms

Is jmesql better option than rms for j2me environment, Is there any limitaions using jmesql. Is rms is better when using large volume of data. What is better to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing a RDBMS to the RMS is a fairly complicated topic but in short, J2ME applications can only use the RMS for internal storage of data so any RDBMS is going to use the RMS to store the data. So you won't get around any of the technical limitations of the RMS but it could make it easier to work with your data, particularly if it contains complicated relationships between distinct groups of data.

A RDBMS may give you some performance benefits but it will be impacted by the limitations of the RMS, e.g. you can't partially load a record store in the RMS so the RDBMS must load an entire record store before selecting only the data you have requested.

JMESQL is in pre-alpha and doesn't appear to have had any active development for almost 2 years so unless you're willing to fix bugs/add new features yourself you would be better looking for a different library.

In most situations you are better using the RMS as it is simpler to work with and has less overhead but it will depend on the data you need to store.